# Authorization of particular endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

can I apply authorization at end point level(method level) if I have allow anonymous at controller level inside net core api?  if yes how can achieve that.

I have tried to do that by applying [authorize] attribute at endpoint level but it didn't work. when I tried to execute that endpoint it execute without authorization

Comment: You would have to remove allow anonymous from the controller and add that onto the endpoints instead

Comment: `It didn't work` doesn't explain anything. Have you checked the docs, eg [Create a Web App with Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-7.0) ? Post the actual code you tried

Comment: Does `endpoint` mean `controller action` in this question? Anonymous access is the default which means you *don't* need to add `AllowAnonymous` to the controller. In the [Simple Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-7.0) examples, `AccountController` has no attribute so the `Login` action is anonymous, allowing everyone to login. The `Logout` action on the other hand has `[Authorize]` which means only authorized users can log out.

Comment: @panagiotis-kanavos yes endpoint mean controller action, so basically i have base controller which apply authorization and i inherit that base controller in another controller .

and that inherited controller has allow anonymous at controller level. so when i try to apply  authorization at one of endpoint it didn't authorize request . so basically it can be executed by everyone authorized and non authorized person

Comment: `i have base controller which apply authorization and i inherit that base controller in another controller` you never said anything about inheritance. What you asked is the default behavior. Edit the question, ask the real question and post the actual code. Although the *best* answer is - don't inherit from that controller

Answer (score 1):

If you apply `[AllowAnonymous]` at controller level or higher, `[Authorize]` will not apply on the covered endpoints.

If only one endpoint needs authorization you need to either apply `[AllowAnonymous]` on the endpoints that don't need authorization or separate authorized endpoints to a different controller (you can still use same routes).

Comment: @dbpadhiyar it would help if you posted what you tried and why. The default access is anonymous, there's no need for extra attributes. You can apply `Authorize` to individual actions. Why did you add `AllowAnonymous` in the first place? Did you encounter another problem?

Comment: @Juunas

so basically i have base controller which apply authorization and i inherit that base controller in another controller . and that inherited controller has allow anonymous at controller level. so when i try to apply authorization at one of endpoint it didn't authorize request . so basically it can be executed by everyone authorized and non authorized person.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need you could implement like this

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult test()
        {
            if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }
             //...
            return Ok("passed authorization");
        }
    }
```